# Issue with a php form

Tags: php

I've created a very basic php form for a website and the form mostly works - only problem is that when the form is emailed to the gmail account, only one line (the "college" line) shows up in the email, with the rest blank. The sender's name ($field_name) appears in the subject line of the message (along with the xxx.Org TShirt Order part of the message), but the only line that appears in the body of the message is the "college part".

Here's the code (I'm aware that it's not sterilized... I'm really new to php and I don't feel like I've got a handle on the language yet, so I'm starting really basic):

```
$mail_to = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$subject = 'xxx.Org TShirt Order - '.$field_name;


$body_message = 'From: ' . $field_name . "\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail Address: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Quantity of Shirts: '.$field_quantity."\n";
$body_message = 'Shirt Style(s): '.$field_which."\n";
$body_message .= 'Size(s): '.$field_size."\n";
$body_message .= 'School: '.$field_school."\n";
$body_message = 'College: '.$field_college."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for placing an order with xxx.Org. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed. Please send an email to xxx@gmail.com');
    window.location = 'contact_page.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed a **dot**,

```
$body_message = 'From: ' . $field_name . "\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail Address: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Quantity of Shirts: '.$field_quantity."\n";
$body_message .= 'Shirt Style(s): '.$field_which."\n";
$body_message .= 'Size(s): '.$field_size."\n";
$body_message .= 'School: '.$field_school."\n";

//add dot in following line too
$body_message .= 'College: '.$field_college."\n";
```

Comment: Actually, he missed a dot in the fourth line as well. < /nitpick >

Answer (score 1):

Your are missing the concatenation of the Body message

```
for string concatenation use 
$body_message .= 'string ';
```

or if you dont want to forget the concatenation operator

```
$body_message= $body_message . " Further string ";
```